# getimagesize function does not working

Tags: php, image

Images in my website is located in other server. I tried to get the size of an image using getimagesize of php and it is not working. It gives an error 'getimagesize is not seekable'. I tried this same function from other server(images are in same server and I change the location of the file, which is using getimagesize function) and it worked. Can anyone solve this?

Comment: Is GD installed with PHP on your server? Does it appear in the output of `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @fredley, looking at the reported error message, this does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: do you mean that you try to run `getimagesize()` on server A to access an image that is on server B ? Or do you mean that you successfully used `getimagesize()` on server A with a local file on server A but it failed on server B with a local file on server B ? I.e. did you call `getimagesize()` with a URL ? In this case, Wrikken is probably right with his answer.

Comment: @Archimedix, I am keeping images in serverA and I have a testing server, called serverB. I tried to get the size of images in serverA from serverB(called the getimagesize function from serverB for the image in serverA) then the getimagesize function return nothing. And when I tried it with other server(called serverC) it is working, I got the width and size of image. I used the url of images in serverA(eg: http://www.domain_name_of_serverA.com/Images/image_name) as the arguement of getimagesize function.

Comment: @fredly, PHP manual shows that GD image library is not required for this function.

Comment: For anyone else coming here experiencing this and random CRAZY slow load times and 500 errors, this solved my problem after about 11 hours: http://www.devnetwork.net/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=134863. Change getimagesize to the filesys not the absolute path.

Answer (score 5):

From the manual:

> filename
>   This parameter specifies the file you wish to retrieve information about. It can reference a local file or (configuration permitting) a remote file using one of the supported streams.

The settings they're talking about (for the [HTTP wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php)) is for the most part having `allow_url_fopen` enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably `could not make seekable` and could mean that PHP / GD cannot recognize the image file as such.

Have you tried with different images and different image formats (GIF, JPG, PNG) ?

Maybe GIF or PNG is not supported by your PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

maybe the image path is wrong

try using this instead:

```
dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])
```

it will return the parent directory's path,

**example:**

```
getimagesize(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/images/sampleimage.jpg');
```